# Android NDK header files not present

Tags: android, header, android-ndk

I would like to use GIO (which is part of GLIB) on Android by using Android NDK.
It seems like the header files of GIO are part of the Android source code. But they are not provided along with the NDK. Is there a way to bring those header files to the NDK.

In other words, my question is. Android source code has header files of a library. But those header files are not present in Android NDK. How can I install those header files into NDK.

ps: no problem changing the android platform

Comment: download your headers through net and use it in your project personally

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just downloading the header files wont work as you need definitions of functions
What you have to do is

-> Download source code of GLIB for android may be from [here](https://github.com/ieei/glib), place it in /PROJECT_HOME/jni,

-> Build the shared library and include it in when building main library (Using LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES. Also don't forget to include this include $(call all-subdir-makefiles) in main Android.mk )

Comment: Thank you. I have been doing something on this line. But I was unaware of the git repo for GLIB. What I had done is to take the GLIB folder in the external/bluetooth/ directory. and put it in the my project_folder. What is difference between the two GLIBs.

Comment: You can build this GLIB simultaneously using ndk-build, and shared object will be created and saved such that it can be used in the main library. You can just place these shared objects created in /libs/armeabi in any project to reuse them directly.